# Jade.js jquery code

Tags: javascript, pug

So im trying to do the following at Jade.js

```
 p(id='microtime')
      script
          var end = Date.now() - start
          var actual = Math.round((end) * 1000) / 1000
          $('microtime').text = 'aa'
```

But the output is the following

```
<var>end = Date.now() - start</var><var>actual = Math.round((end) * 1000) / 1000</var>$('microtime').text = 'aa'
```

I even tried this

- var end = Date.now() - start
- var actual = Math.round((end) * 1000) / 1000
- $('microtime').text = 'aa'

But I get this

```
$('microtime').text = 'aa' undefined is not a function at eval
```

Comment: `start` is undefined?

Comment: its just a Date.now()

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#plaintext) suggest:

> just add a . after the tag (with no preceding space)

```
p(id='microtime')
    script.
        var end = Date.now() - start
        var actual = Math.round((end) * 1000) / 1000
        $('microtime').text = 'aa'
```